# Factory Girl reference parent

Tags: ruby-on-rails, factory-bot

I have a Factory like this:

```
FactoryGirl.define do
    factory :subject do
      name 'Calculus'
    end
end
```

And I would like to reference that his parent is 'Maths' which parent is null.  How should I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand the question correctly, you can specify a parent as an option to the `factory` method:

```
FactoryGirl.define do
  factory :subject do
    name 'Subject'
  end

  factory :maths, :parent => :subject do
    name 'Maths'
  end

  factory :calculus, :parent => :maths do
    name 'Calculus'
  end
end
```

This is a fairly contrived example since the child factories override the inherited `name` attribute, but does that answer your question?